# Getting the sum of several comboboxes value into a single textbox

Tags: excel, vba

A simple Point of Sale system, that shows 2 product: Apple and Banana each price of 10.  I need to have a display of the total sum.

I used cmbApple_Change() event
I used if elseif statement

I was able to get the result only for 1 combobox.

```
Private Sub cmbApple_Change()

If cmbApple.Value = 0 Then
    txtTotal.Text = 0
ElseIf cmbApple.Value = 1 Then
    txtTotal.Text = 10
ElseIf cmbApple.Value = 2 Then
    txtTotal.Text = 20
ElseIf cmbApple.Value = 3 Then
    txtTotal.Text = 30
End If

End Sub
```

[image: GIF]

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: `txtTotal.Text = cmbApple.Value + cmbBanana.Value` this should work

Comment: Combobox only represents the number of product to be purchase. Apple adn Banana is 10 php only. my code only works for apple but I wanted to include there the banana.

Comment: You would need to add another event (`cmbBanana_Change()`) to track changes in your banana ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you will always have the total value:

```
Private Sub cmbApple_Change()

    Dim BananaItems As Byte
    Dim AppleItems As Byte

    On Error Resume Next
    AppleItems = cmbApple.Value
    BananaItems = cmbBanana.Value
    On Error GoTo 0

    TxtTotal.Text = AppleItems * 10 + BananaItems * 10

End Sub
Private Sub cmbBanana_Change()

    Dim BananaItems As Byte
    Dim AppleItems As Byte

    On Error Resume Next
    AppleItems = cmbApple.Value
    BananaItems = cmbBanana.Value
    On Error GoTo 0

    TxtTotal.Text = AppleItems * 10 + BananaItems * 10

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Byte

    With cmbApple
        For i = 0 To 5
            .AddItem (i)
        Next i
    End With
    With cmbBanana
        For i = 0 To 5
            .AddItem (i)
        Next i
    End With    

End Sub
```

It is simple, but works for your example. In case you need to change the price often there are other ways.

Edit: Check the edited answer, also changed your code to add items, you can change the `For i = 0 to 5` to any number you want (max 256)

Comment: I got an error Error 13: Type Mismatch. I even change the property of txtTotal to value instead of Text.

Comment: Wasn't working for you?? Is the same code but for both items.

Comment: Yeah it's not working for me..I got the error I mention.

Comment: @BambooFox check my answer now

Comment: you're genius Buddy..Thank you so much..Now I can include this code to my project. Please check my previous question, I have a commandButton there that would move the data to excel sheet.